# Input 3 and 1 channel input to the network in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

My dataset consists mostly of 3 channel images, but i also have a few 1 channel images,Is it possible to train a network that takes in both 3 channels and 1 channels as inputs?

Any suggestions are welcome,Thanks in advance,

Comment: I do not think what you are saying is easy to implement because the weights should be of fixed sized, but definitely you can identify the 1 channel images in the data-preprocessing part and then copy it three times to make a 3 channel image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the grayscale images by checking the size and apply some transformation to have 3 channels.

It seems to be better to convert images from grayscale to RGB than simply copying the image three times on the channels.

You can do that by `cv2.cvtColor(gray_img, cv.CV_GRAY2RGB)` if you have `opencv-python` installed.

If you want a clean implementation you can extend `torchvision.transform` with a new `Transform` that does this job automatically.

Comment: How would be the this `Transform` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Load your images and convert them to RGB:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
```