# Is there a PyTorch transform to go from 1 Channel data to 3 Channels?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I am using the emnist data set via the PyTorch datasets together with a neural network that expects a 3 Channel input.

I would like to use PyTorch transforms to copy my 1D greyscale into 3D so I can use the same net for 1D and 3D data.

Which transform can I use? Or how would I extend PyTorch transforms as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50530923/18895809

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by using `torchvision.transforms.Grayscale` with `num_output_channels` [parameter](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.functional.to_grayscale.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.to_grayscale) set to `3`.

Example usage:

```py
trafos = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=3),
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
])
```

Functional interface (i.e. `torchvision.transforms.to_grayscale(num_output_channels=3)`) also supports the same parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Training-wise I recommend using `img.expand(...)` as it does not allocate new memory see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html) instead of concatenation `torch.cat`. While doing so keep in mind that a 3 channel image (possibly RGB) is structurally quiet different from a gray scale one (I suspect you may have some degradation in your results.)

```py
import torch
img = torch.zeros((1, 200, 200))
img = img.expand(3,*img.shape[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
import torch

img = torch.zeros((1, 200, 200))            # img shape = (1, 200, 200)
img2 = torch.cat([img, img, img], dim=0)    # img shape2 = (3, 200, 200)
```

If you prefer, you can even code your own transformation based on the above snippet.
You need to create a simple callable class, just as described by the wiki at:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/custom_dataset_transforms_loader.html